# Twig - дочерние шаблоны

Tags: php, twig, шаблонизаторы

Здравствуйте.

Недавно начал изучать Twig, и совсем не понимаю как работать с дочерними шаблонами (лайаутами).

Как мне отправлять данные в дочерний лайаут, чтобы после вывода основного лайаута, дочерние отображались с переданными данными. Или тут надо все лайауты с данными строить по кусочкам а потом собирать?

Ну вот как тут, к примеру, передать массив **menu** лайауту **menu.twig**:

**index.php**

```
/*...CODE...*/
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($twig_filesystem);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => TWIG_CACHE,
    'debug' => TWIG_DEBUG));

$twig->display('main.twig', array());
/*...CODE...*/
```

**main.twig**

```
/*...CODE...*/
{% include "header.twig" %}
/*...CODE...*/
```

**header.twig**

```
/*...CODE...*/
{% include "menu.twig" %}
/*...CODE...*/
```

**menu.twig**

```
/*...CODE...*/
{% for link in menu %}
<li><a href="{{link.href}}">{{ link.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
/*...CODE...*/
```

**Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!**

**UPD:** хотя бы ссылок дайте, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то сложно вы страницу строите. Посмотрите раздел Extends http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html
Проще создать один главный (или пару) шаблон, наследоваться от него и создавать похожие шаблоны переопределяя блоки.

А про переменные в include смотрите http://x-twig.ru/tags/include/ они передаются

```
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

Т.е. передаете в основной шаблон переменные, в основном шаблоне указываете какие переменные передать дочернему при include

Comment: Ну, в принципе, так как вы предложили тоже можно. Я просто думал что можно передать данные с контроллера в дочерний шаблон.

Comment: twig был бомба потому, что у него был Extends, а сейчас и smarty это поддерживает. В общем Extends рулит, особенно если шаблоны друг от друга не сильно отличаются. Если наоборот - шаблоны сильно отличаются, но есть немного общих частей то include

Answer (score 1):

Очень полезно бывает читать [документацию](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html). Вот краткая выдержка из неё:

```
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}

{% set vars = {'foo': 'bar'} %}
{% include 'template.html' with vars %}
```

Соответственно переменные можно создавать не только в шаблоне, но и передавать из скрипта.

Comment: Не понял, а как с контроллера передать данные? Отправить их в основной лайаут а потом распределять по дочерним?

Comment: @KRasul, `$twig->render('main.twig', ['vars' => ['foo' => 'bar']]);` . Я в своих проектах использую `render`, вместо `display`. Честно - не читал в чём разница.

Comment: `display` он выводит данные сразу (**echo** не нужен), а `render` можно использовать когда необходимо данные лайаута в переменную загнать, ну или тоже вывести добавив **echo**.

Comment: А по сути одно и то же